# multiple validations Rails 3 (Rails for Zombies; 2:3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working through Rails for Zombies, loving the helpful tutorial and interested in others by the way....

My issue is as follows.

The tutorial ask me to

"Do both uniqueness and presence validation on a Zombie's name on a single line, using the new syntax"

I have tried the following in the console at RfZ;

---

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, validates_presence_of :name
end
```

// AND  //

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates Name :uniqueness, :presence => true
end
```

The tutorial is asking for the new Rails 3 syntax. I understand the new syntax allows for multiple validation arguments in one line. Very nice, but how would I do this? Thanks in advance everyone.

-Ryan

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your second attempt is closer, but not quite correct. Try this:

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :uniqueness => true, :presence => true
end
```

FYI, the older syntax would be :

```
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validateS_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

Comment: Rob, you rock, thanks. I totally appreciate it, that worked I see why too.

Comment: No problems! Note: you should generally accept an answer that satisfies your question so that your question is closed, and so that people searching Stack Overflow can find the answer if they have a similar question.

Comment: OK. Let me take a second to figure this out so I can accept your answer Rob, thanks again.

Comment: Click the ✔ to the left of this answer :P

Answer (score 6):

```
validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
```

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It was the first answer to the question AFAIK

Comment: Toxic community. Happens everywhere.